# how to set flex-column childs from left to right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to set flex items from left to right in flex-column layout.

### What I have now

[image: 1]

### Desired Layout

[image: 2]

My Code:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items:flex-end;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-content: flex-end;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: Without any of your code there is little we can help you with. Please add your HTML and CSS related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wrap-reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;

  height: 400px;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div> 
  <div class="flex-item"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: The solution is correct, I think these 3 property for flex-container should be enough to achieve  what is required  here.
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;

Answer (score 0):

add this code in css where you define `display: flex`

example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  
  }
  
  .flex div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex" >
  <div>
    box -1 
  </div>
  <div>
    box -2
  </div>
  <div>
     box -3
  </div>
  <div>
     box -4
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try out `direction:column-reverse` .You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)